# The type arguments for method 'InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<Tmodel,Tpropery>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here it's my errors when I try to add `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)`:

1)The type or namespace name 'Book' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

2)The type or namespace name 'Book' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

3)The type arguments for method `InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<Tmodel,Tpropery>(HtmlHelper<TModel>,Expression<Func<TModel,Tproperty>>)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

**My view:**

```
@model Book
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Buy";
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Buy", "Home", FormMethod.Post))

{


    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)


}
```

**My model:**

```
  public class Book
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

I have controller for my view.

Comment: Use the fully qualified name of your class, or add a `@using` statement in your view for the assembly you model is in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not shure whats the problem is, but i think, that you have to add the namespace of the `Book` type. Something like that:

```
@model WebApplication.Models.Book
```